# Why are some of the lower leaves on my cactus turning brown?

Tags: leaves, cactus, damage

I have a cactus standing on my windowsill and for years it seemed pretty healthy, but last month its leaves started to turn a light brown-pinkish, kind of like a salt stone lamp. They also look a bit dry, but don't feel very different. Some of the other leaves are starting to look purple as well.

- It hasn't been moved for about five years.
- I don't really water it regularly, just when I remember it or when it looks dry.
- I live near Munich, and yes, we did have *a bit* weird weather pattern lately. (Four weeks ago it was still snowing, and now it's about 30°C, 86°F.)

What's wrong and is there something I can do?

[image]

Comment: These are really hard lived. It might get a little dry, but this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing okay. The bottom browned leaves are dead.

If you wish, you could repot in a bigger pot, and/or add fertilizer (not really needed, but you can give a very little bit)/more water, or just leave it alone, and it will probably do okay for a while.

If you do want to help it or have it look greener, you can cut off the lower, dead leaves, allowing for more ventilation, and repot it.